# Android the navigation toolbar icon and logo can not align

Tags: android, toolbar, statusbar, android-appcompat

[image: the logo cannot align to the left drawer icon]
The toolbar layout I set android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
but it not work

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon" />
```

main layout:

```
<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/head_tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/head_tool_bar" />

</RelativeLayout>
<!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container. -->
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.voogolf.helper.home.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/drawer_new_home" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How can I set drawer icon and logo align top? Why left drawer icon have padding 
like this?

[image]

Comment: what is the imageview in this?

Comment: its better if you add these items inside a relative or linear layout which are in toolbar.

Comment: I remove my custom imageview in toolbar,and toolbar.setLogo(),but result is the same as the above picture, can not algin the left drawer icon, why?

Answer (score 0):

add this property attribute to imageView `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"`

Comment: You can wrap your text and image views inside a linear layout and try to set its gravity

Answer (score 0):

you should try setting layout gravity like this.

```
android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
```

and make sure `padding` and `margin` is `0dp`

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to customize your `toolbar` then do something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
     ...>
<RelativeLayout>
<ImageView
    ... />
//here you can add more view items
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

if you have used toolbar and setting up the action bar using `ActionBarDrawerToggle` then add this code to your `ActionBarDrawerToggle` object.

```
toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);     // this will disable your default haburger icon
toggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_custom_drawer_icon);  // this will replace the toggle home indicator
```

Comment: If I customize toolbar, how set a ImageView left instead of left drawer icon and bind to drawerToggle.

Comment: if you are trying to replace the drawer toggle icon, then its a different thing. for that you need to code. You don't need to add an imageview. Will update on this in some time.

Answer (score 0):

Android support v7 toolbar is just like other views. You can customize or add whatever the view you are required inside the toolbar.
Your `imageView` should be inside the `toolbar` and make `imageView` aligned whatever you want by `gravity or layout_gravity` attribute.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/home_button"
        android:background="@color/colorToolbarWelcomeBg"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/back_arrow"
        android:layout_gravity="left|centre"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:background="@color/colorToolbarWelcomeBg"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/welcomeToManager"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and place this layout inside `<toolbar> Above layout </toolbr>` This code showing just an idea not actual code :)

Comment: how to set home_button animation open drawer like toggle icon animation

Answer (score 0):

This is my toolbar with a back button and text in center.You can refer this code.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            android:contentInsetStart="0dp"

            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
                    android:layout_width="25dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/back_arrow" />


                <com.indosat.rider.views.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_custom_title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Register Page"
                    style="@style/roboto_medium"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="19sp" />



            </FrameLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Let me know if you need any help in arranging your final setup.